# interpret estimated marginal means (emmans aka lsmeans): negative response values

Tags: r, lme4, emmeans

I am working on a a model with `lmer` where I would like to get estimated marginal means with the `emmeans`library. This is my dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("CCF", "UN"), class = "factor"), level = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "F", "H", "L"
), class = "factor"), random = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("1.6", "2", "3.2", "5", NA), class = "factor"), 
    continuous = c(72.7951770264767, 149.373765810534, 1.64153094886205, 
    54.6697408615215, 25.5801835808851, 1.45794117443253, 25.3660934894788, 
    91.2321704897132, 2.75353217433675, 44.1995276851725, 33.1854545470435, 
    5.36536076058866, 29.6807620242672, 80.6077496067764, 0.833434180091457, 
    13.6789475327185, 77.4930412025109, 3.65998714174906, 25.2848344605563, 
    136.632099849828, 2.56715261161435, 28.6733878840584, 66.800616194317, 
    1.37475468782539, 23.007491380183, 84.980285774607, 1.13569710795522, 
    33.8610875632139, 56.1234827517798, 1.32327007970416, 60.0843812879313, 
    43.4487832450889, 1.14942423621912, 53.6673704529947, 146.746167255051, 
    3.91593723271292, 27.0321687961004, 89.5925729244878, 1.47707078226047, 
    44.0523211310831, 115.087908243373, 1.94039630728038, 86.4074806697431, 
    43.3266206881612, 2.81456503996437, 66.868588961071, 229.797526052566, 
    1.07971524769264, 30.3390107111747, 116.680801084036, 1.67711446647817, 
    69.0961010697534, 78.5454363192614, 1.92137892126384, 53.5708546850303, 
    37.7175476710608, 1.96087397451467, 25.5166981770257, 37.3755071788757, 
    2.21602000526086, 10.3266195584378, 38.1458490762217, 2.7508022340832, 
    44.5864920143771, 8.45382647692274, 2.63204944520792, 87.5376946978593, 
    27.2354119098268, 3.38134648323956, 26.8815471706502, 14.5539972194568, 
    2.0556994322415, 27.4619977737491, 32.8546665896602, 2.66809379088059, 
    42.3815445857533, 21.3359802201685, 2.19167325121191, 53.3189825439001, 
    13.5708790223439, 2.22274607227071, 88.297423835906, 8.50554349658773, 
    3.5764241495006, 29.284865737912, 21.1213079519954, 2.3070166819956, 
    10.7659615128225, 33.4813413290485, 2.49896565066211, 59.0935696616465, 
    13.2863515051715, 4.36424795471221, 72.1627847396763, 9.09326343200557, 
    2.13701784901259, 27.5824079679471, 8.84486812842272, 1.98293342019671, 
    17.5321126287485, 19.1806349705231, 5.03952187899644, 58.3473975730234, 
    9.17287686145614, 2.99575072457674)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
105L))
```

This is my model:

```
library(lme4)
    model <- lmer((continuous) ~  treatment + level + (1|random), data= df, REML = TRUE)
```

The data as it is does not meet the model assumptions, but still I am wondering why I get a negative estimated marginal mean (response) on treatment "UN" level "L" (see `lettering` table) when I don't have any negative numbers in `df$continuous`?

```
library(multcompView)
library(emmeans)
lsm.mixed_C <- emmeans::emmeans(my_model,pairwise ~  treatment * level, type="response")
lettering <- CLD(lsm.mixed_C,alpha=0.05,Letters=letters,
                         adjust= "tukey")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is because you badly need to include the interaction in your model. Compare:

```
model2 <- lmer((continuous) ~  treatment * level + (1|random), 
               data= df, REML = TRUE)
emmip(model2, treatment ~ level)
```

[image]

with:

```
emmip(model, treatment ~ level)
```

[image]

In `model2`, both EMMs at level `L` are close to zero. If you remove the interaction from the model, you force those two profiles to be parallel, while maintaining a sizeable positive difference between treatments `CCF` and `UN`, forcing the estimate for `UN` to go negative. In actual fact, though, all six estimates for `treatment` x `level` combinations are seriously distorted.

I can't repeat it enough. `emmeans()` summarizes a *model*. If you give it a bad model, you get dumb results. Thanks for the great illustration of this point.

Comment: Yes, I did notice that there were significant interactions in `model2`: 
fixed effects:

`library(lmerTest)
model2_pv <- lmer((continuous) ~  treatment * level + (1|random), 
               data= df, REML = TRUE)
fixed <-  as.data.frame(coef(summary(model2_pv))`

I thought though that when I run an anova of the two models, what I want to pick is the lower AIC with an explanatory power that is not lower that the model with no interactions (see `anova_compare`). That led me to think that the model with no interactions was a preferable choiche:

`anova_compare <- anova(model1, model2)`

Comment: Well, it may be that the additive model is the better choice when accounting for pronounced error or subject variation, but a consequence of that model is that negative EMM. Look at residual plots. Maybe a log transformation or something is justified — if so, that’s another way of avoiding our-of-range estimates.

Comment: Thank you. Would `glmer` be an option for my `df` instead of `lmer` if I cannot address the assumptions issue? Or any other suggestions? `df` contains two factor explanatory variables (`treatment` and `level`), the dependent continuous variable `continuous` and the `random` factor variable.

Comment: Fit the best model you can. `emmeans()` does work with `glmer` objects — and many others.

Comment: I looked again at your data. (1) With `plot(residuals(model2) ~ predict(model2))`, there is the classic fanning-out pattern. If you re-fit with `log(continuous)` as the response, the residual plot is fairly homoscedastic. (2) With either the transformed or untransformed model, `anova()` shows the interaction is highly significant. I don't see a justification for a model without the interaction, and a `glmer` model of some stripe seems unnecessary.

Comment: Note: `anova(model, model2)` results in a *P* value of 2.06 x 10^-9. That screams to include the interaction; did you misread it?

Comment: I appreciate now that the P value has to be <0.05. I am under the impression that Crawley 2013 The R book uses the other way around